# How to automatically bring in jar-with-dependencies when specifying an artifact

Tags: java, maven

I have a jar that my project depends on but there is also a utility that's contained in that library but in order for that utility to work, I need ALL of the dependencies that the main JAR depends on.

The maker of the library provides it with jar-with-dependencies.jar file that is also in the central maven repo.

However, when I simply specify the groupId/artifactId/version, all I see in my `.m2/repository` directory is the main jar, but not the one `jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

How do I automatically download that `jar-with-dependencies.jar` of that library? Do I specify something special when I specify that library as a dependency in my `pom.xml`?

Comment: IMHO the correct way would be to create an empty maven project, add the library as dependency and add the plugin to build a jar-with dependencies using the main class of the library stand-alone util.

Answer (score 1):

You can use classifier option when declaring the dependency, if the dependency that you are trying to add follows the standard Maven naming conventions. 
Below is an example.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
</dependency>
```

This will fetch **REPO_PATH**/com/group/artifact/artifact-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar from the repository.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the caveat here; adding that without having a good understanding of what you're including could lead to having multiple (possibly incompatible) versions of the same libraries in the CLASSPATH.  This can lead to difficult-to-diagnose errors later.  Best practice is to go ahead and include the dependencies in your own project and handle version discrepancies.

Comment: Is it common for a repository to have each library in the "jar" version and the "jar-with-dependencies"? I don't have much experience on this but I would assume no. And then using the classifier "jar-with-dependencies" will not work as it can only fetch what is present in the repository.

Comment: @Gus I don't actually need it to be part of the CLASSPATH. I just need the users to download it so they can use it as an executable java -jar. It's like a support utility to generate certain types of files. I guess, it's best to just provide a link and have the users download it directly from maven central???

Comment: @Ramu Gudelli Thanks! I think doing that with a classifier will actually add that jar to the classpath. Not what I want. I just want it downloaded into the .m2/repository directory. The user will have to manually execute `java -jar ~/.m2/repository/...` . I was just wondering if there is any way for maven to pull it down automatically once it's pulling down the main jar anyway. I don't want it in the classpath through

Comment: @user1902183 Sorry, Accidentally entered the last comment without finishing.

If you just need the jar-with-dependencies jar downloaded to your local repository, you can use maven plugins. You can configure the plugin(see below) in your pom.xml to download the file during your project build.

Below are links to 2 different plugins and the documentation should give you an idea on how to use them.

https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/download-single-mojo.html

https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin